# Count rows in selection (all areas) via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If a non-contiguous area is selected (in Excel) `Selection.Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in the first area. Is there a different way to count the rows in all areas (then to loop through all the areas in the selection manually)?

Preferably I'm looking for a build-in function of some sort.

Comment: No. You need to loop. And it may be a non-trivial task, i.e. what happens if one area overlaps the same row(s) as another, e.g. `Range("A1:B5,D3:E8")`.

Comment: @BigBen Important point, thanks! I'll post my solution in an answer later on. I was just wondering if there is a library of such common functions somewhere. Or another good way to keep my own function that accumulate over time organized.

Comment: Maybe someone has a similar solution already on GitHub.

Comment: For the exact same selected range you'll also get different results depending on how the cells were selected...

Comment: @TimWilliams you mean s.th. else then what BigBen already commented on?!

Comment: @BigBen good idea, I'll check it...

Comment: Yes- the same selected range can have different areas depending on how the selection was made. But you likely don't need to worry about that if (eg) you're just dealing with a filtered table, and not some random user-selected range.

Comment: @TimWilliams ah ok, I think I get it now, although the "overall selection" might be the same in two instances the areas might be different?!

Comment: Yes - that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"And it may be a non-trivial task" sounds like a challenge...lol.

```
Public Function GetRowsCount(ByVal Target As Range) As Long
'Counts number of rows in all selected areas
'Rows in overlapping areas will only be counted once

    Dim Area As Range
    Dim Row As Range
    Dim Map As New Collection
    
    For Each Area In Target.Areas
        For Each Row In Area.Rows
            On Error Resume Next
            Map.Add Row.Row, CStr(Row.Row)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    Next
    
    GetRowsCount = Map.Count
End Function
```

Comment: I assume the Map.Add get's rid of the "double rows" for overlapping areas, throwing a error" if the row has already been added to the collection (I haven't looked it up yet)?!

Comment: Haha. Non-trivial was a bit of a stretch then.

Comment: @TinMan I added that info as a comment inside the function

Comment: @TinMan thanks, I just read that "ByVal" is not the default in VBA, didn't know that. Actually I didn't realize that you can pass on ByRef in VBA. Since most "solution" use a global variable between two procedures. Using ByRef should solve that, right?!

Comment: @Albin Yes.  ByRef parameters are preferred over Global variables.  If you are interested in improving your coding style, you should join [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @TinMan Interesting, I haven't notice Code Review yet... I suppose this question would have been a good question for that network as well.

Comment: @Albin CR is strictly for working code.  Although a large number of VBA posts are looking to improve performance, the mission is to improve the code provided.  Suggests best practices, naming conventions, different approaches etc.

Comment: @TinMan that's clear, I would have put it there 1:1 but included my current (working) code snipped.